# Changing style of pagination page numbers

Tags: css, laravel

I'm trying to use pagination in Laravel 5.2 , using `{{$word->links()}}`
The page numbers are showing vertically as shown below, although I need to make them horizontal.

[image]

Comment: We're gonna need to see some code.

Comment: check next answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501691/laravel-v5-2-pagination-display

Comment: You need to customize pagination blade and tweak the css - https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your screenshot i understood your code should be like the below one, Try this

```css
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
}
ul li{
    margin: 10px;
    background: #8BC34A;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align:center
}
ul li a{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#FFF;
}
ul li:first-child, ul li:last-child{
    min-width:100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```